# Browser events to close the application

Tags: browser

How to trigger the action script when the browser is closed in Flex? What I want is when the browser is closed, an alert has to be shown with options to continue or not. Later the event should be stored in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot listen for an event outside of the browser window. You are "sandboxed" to the browser window only.

Comment: my had audit module recording every action of the user,so i want the logout action to be record if the borwser is close suddenly ,hw do i work with it ,